# How to import custom svgs icon in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Can anybody let me know the proper and complete steps to make custom icons of "svg's" that I have in react native

Comment: Hello, welcome to stackoverflow. Please try to update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example, details on any issues and error messages, and actual and expected results. It's difficult to impossible to assist otherwise.

Comment: https://github.com/vault-development/react-native-svg-uri I think the best to import custom svgs in react native with great ease is via using above package

Comment: @nishitchittora I used the library and after that I am getting warnings like

" Rename componentWillMount to UNSAFE_componentWillMount to suppress this warning in non-strict mode. In React 17.x, only the UNSAFE_ name will work. To rename all deprecated lifecycles to their new names, you can run `npx react-codemod rename-unsafe-lifecycles` in your project source folder."
Please let me know how to solve this problem